# What is 1 XOR 1 XOR 1?

Tags: boolean, logic, xor, algebra

so I know that 1 XOR 1 will be 0, and 1 XOR 0 will be 1
What will 1 XOR 1 XOR 1 be?
I just started learning so I am really new to this
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: analogy: you know that 1 + 1 = 2 and 2 + 1 = 3. So what is 1 + 1 + 1?

Comment: I'm confused. You seem to already know the answer. Why the uncertainty?

Comment: I believe that you can express `1 XOR 1 XOR 1` as `(1 XOR 1) XOR 1` which should lead you to the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra / [math.se] instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1 XOR 1 equals 0

1 XOR 0 equals 1
```

So it is 1. You can always decomposite.